# Using boto Upload file to S3 sub folder when I have no permissions on listing folders of S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I have a sub-folder "my/places/photos" inside my bucket "basebucket". I have read write and delete permissions on this sub folder. However I have no permissions on the basebucket.

Is there a using Python boto that I can do multipart upload files to "my/places/photos".

I wrote the following code but not working.The bucket object itself is not getting created. Gives me an exception. If I try lookup I am getting bucket object as None.

```
def file_multipart_upload():
    conn = S3Connection(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY)
    bucket = conn.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

    # Get file info
    file_to_upload = FILE_TO_UPLOAD
    source_size = os.stat(file_to_upload).st_size
    chunk_size = 5242880

    # Create a multipart upload request
    mp = bucket.initiate_multipart_upload(os.path.join(BUCKET_FOLDER_PATH, file_to_upload))
    chunk_count = int(math.ceil(source_size / float(chunk_size)))
    print("Chunk size is {0} for the file {1}".format(chunk_count, file_to_upload))

    # Send the file parts, using FileChunkIO to create a file-like object
    # that points to a certain byte range within the original file. We
    # set bytes to never exceed the original file size.
    for i in range(chunk_count):
        offset = chunk_size * i
        bytes = min(chunk_size, source_size - offset)
        with FileChunkIO(file_to_upload, 'r', offset=offset, bytes=bytes) as fp:
            mp.upload_part_from_file(fp, part_num=i + 1)
        print("Offset, bytes and part_num values of file {0} are {1}, {2} and {3}".format(file_to_upload, offset,
                                                                                          bytes, i + 1))
    # Finish the upload
    mp.complete_upload()
```

Comment: By the way I am using boto 2.38 and not boto3.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the boto `get_bucket` method call tries to validate that the bucket exists by performing a `HEAD` request on the bucket url.  This would require that you have permissions to list the bucket.

If you want to avoid this validation step, simply do this:

```
bucket = conn.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME, validate=False)
```

and boto will skip the validation step.